# How do I update state (open,complete) in a silverlight/odata project for Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: silverlight-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a silverlight app hosted in CRM 2011 online. I have functionality where I am updating a phone call and display two fields in a small form. I have the requirement to mark as complete but I seem to be failing here.

I have:

```
phoneCall.StateCode.Value = 1;

phoneCall.Subject = activity.Subject;
phoneCall.Description = activity.Description;

_context.UpdateObject(phoneCall);
_context.BeginSaveChanges(OnChangesSaved, phoneCall);
```

The subject works and saves as well as the description but the statecode does not. StateCode is not null this is an existing object and it's currently set to 0 (open). The save does not affect the StateCode. I have this in a try-catch and no error is being reported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The status of a record cannot be changed with an `Update` message. In order to change the statecode or status code, you have to issue a [`SetStateRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.setstaterequest.aspx).

```
var setStateRequest = new SetStateRequest
{
  EntityMoniker = new EntityReference({LogicalName}, {Id}),
  State = new OptionSetValue(1),
  Status = new OptionSetValue(1)
};

_context.Execute(setStateRequest);
```

#### Update

---

The REST endpoint has some [limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334279.aspx).

> The REST endpoint provides an alternative to the WCF SOAP endpoint, but there are currently some limitations.
>
> - Only Create, Retrieve, Update and Delete actions can be performed on entity records
>     Messages that require the Execute method cannot be performed.

This means for you: you cannot alter the state with the REST endpoint. You have to use the WCF SOAP endpoint for this task.

Comment: The SetStateRequest is used in the SDK I am using the REST service in a silverlight app hosted on CRM 2011 Online. SetStateRequest does not exist in that service.